# How to use SQLITE_STATIC in python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I searched around and did not find how to use SQLITE_STATIC in sqlite3 of python. Is it available? I am very new to sqlite3 and database. I was surprised when my search found nothing. Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks to me as if Python's SQLite package always uses SQLITE_TRANSIENT: https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=SQLITE_TRANSIENT

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was told changing from SQLITE_TRANSIENT to SQLITE_STATIC might increase the speed for inserting rows. Do you know if this is true?